# Two arrays into one Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I would like to create a

```
 Dictionary<string, int[]> dict
```

out of two arrays:

```
string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D" };
int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 2 };
```

the result:

```
["A"] = {1,5} 
["B"] = {2}
["D"] = {2}
```

Is there a way i can do this with LINQ?
I have read about Zip but I don't think I can use since I need to add values to an existing key.value array.

Comment: What do you mean by I need to add value? In your current case for key A you will have value 6 or 5 ?

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion. I want to add another value into the array whenever the key already exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.Zip` to bind the two collections together and then `GroupBy` to group the keys.

```
string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D" };
int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 2 };

var result = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
                 .GroupBy(item => item.k, selection => selection.v)
                 .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.ToArray());
```

Then to add these items into the dictionary that you already have:
*I changed the `int[]` to `List<int>` so it is easier to handle `Add/AddRange`*

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> existingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (existingDictionary.ContainsKey(item.Key))
        existingDictionary[item.Key].AddRange(item.Value);
    else
        existingDictionary.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToList());
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was hoping Zip would work but I missed the .groupby! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*Linq* solution:

```
  string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D" };
  int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 2 };

  Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = keys
    .Zip(values, (k, v) => new {
       key = k,
       value = v })
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.value)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                  chunk => chunk.ToArray());
```

Test:

```
  string report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict
    .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} [{string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}]"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
  A [1, 5]
  B [2]
  D [2]
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! Will test this

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            string[] keys = { "A", "B", "A", "D" };
            int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 2 };

            Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = keys.Select((x, i) => new { key = x, value = values[i] }).GroupBy(x => x.key, y => y.value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToArray());
```